# There was an error parsing the SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Ok so I'm just trying to pull the last record entered into a table and get a specific value from it.  I've looked all over the net to try and find a viable means to do so to fit my needs but everything I try comes up short....

I keep getting

> There was an error parsing the query. [token line number = , token 
>   line offset = , token in error = ]

The queries where I get this the most is using an `ORDER BY` statement.

I have the key for my tables labeled as "Index" instead of "ID"; I keep trying simple queries like

```
SELECT *
FROM   Departments
WHERE  Valid = @validation
ORDER  BY Index ASC
```

but I get an error saying the *"token in error = Index"*

Now I have a query I need to run that selects the very last record in a table and gets it's JobID which is not the same as the Index.  So I tried my tried and true

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM   TableName
ORDER  BY Index DESC
```

In this way I can get other data as well.  But I get the same error code.

So I tried

```
SELECT MAX(Index)
FROM   TableName
```

same error.

No matter what I try it doesn't want to select by the Index, which is set as Primary Key, Auto Increment, etc....

Comment: `Index` is a reserved word in SQL.  Try adding braces around it, like this: `[Index]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am totally shooting from the hip here but, `Index` is a [reserved word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL.

From the [SQL Server compact documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174147.aspx):

> You must delimit identifiers when they do not comply with the rules
>   for the format of regular identifiers *or when reserved keywords are
>   used as identifiers*.

```
+----------------------------+---------------------------------+
|         Delimiter          | Usage in SQL Server Compact 4.0 |
+----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Brackets [ ]               | Not supported                   |
| Double quotation marks " " | Noncompliant identifiers:       |
| Single quotation marks ' ' | String data values              |
+----------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

So I suggest that you do the following with your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Departments
WHERE  Valid = @validation
ORDER  BY "Index" ASC
```

Adding the `""` around `Index` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of the fact that it was a reserved word... lol  I'm losing my touch.  BTW, simply adding Double-Quotes wont work just by adding them in... but yah I forgot to delimit it.  Easier to just rebuild the databases so it wont be a problem later.